# How do i show Banner Adview bottom of screen with SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, swiperefreshlayout, adview

To summarize my problem:
I have a RecylerView that I use inside SwiperRefreshLayout.
Except for these two, I want to add a banner adview to the bottom of the screen.
When I add the tag `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` above SwipeRefreshLayout it looks like this:

[image: Tag at top]

but when I add the adview's tag below SwipeRefreshLayout it disappears. Only Recylerview appears on the screen.

There isn't adview:

[image: Tag at bottom]

> **How can I pin the ad to the bottom of the screen?**

**my codes are like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blur"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        android:layout_above="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should use Constraint Layout instead of Linear, there's no perfect way to keep a view at the bottom in a linear layout. Other than that, Constraint Layout is more performant than Linear, you should always use linear if possible and it's always possible.

Comment: @Praveen this solution solved my problem thanks

Comment: I have a typo in the above comment. 

`Constraint Layout is more performant than Linear, you should always use linear if possible`



What I actually meant is, you should always use a Constraint layout